# Candidates for local extrema of $f(x)=3^{4x/\pi}+\sin x, \qquad x\in[0,\pi]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find all the candidates for the local extrema of max and min for the function $$f(x)=3^{4x/\pi}+\sin x, \qquad x\in[0,\pi]$$

I know at $x=0$ and $x=\pi$ there is a global min and max within this domain, however, how do I prove that there isn't any other candidates. Also, I have tried to compute the additional candidates through the derivative of the function. However, I couldn't compute a value of $x$ such that 
$$ f'(x)= \frac{4e^\frac{4x\ln{3}}{\pi}\ln{3}}{\pi} + \cos{x} = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

In the derivative, $3>e$ so $\ln 3>1$. Also $4>\pi$. Therefore the numerical factors in front of $3^{4x/\pi}$ are greater than $1$. For the given interval $3^{4x/\pi}>1$. Since the cosine term cannot be smaller than $-1$, you don't have any solution for $f'(x)=0$ in the given interval.

Answer (score 1):

It's sufficient to show that $f'(x)$ doesn't have any $0$ in $[0,\infty)$. This is true because

$$ 3^{4x/\pi} > 1, \forall x > 0 $$

Therefore

$$ \frac{4\ln 3}{\pi}3^{4x/\pi} + \cos x > \frac{4\ln 3}{\pi} + \cos x > 0 $$

Since $f(x)$ is always increasing in $[0,\pi]$, $f(\pi)$ is the maximum